# Input not working in Qbasic

Tags: text, input, console, qbasic

I've begun learning Qbasic. For a beginner exercise, I started with a simple text game. A mountain is located "north", and when you type "north" the console should print "Mountain" after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>. However, when "north" is typed and <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, the code is not being executed. Is this just a beginner's mistake? Should I be pressing something different than <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Here's the code:

```
CLS
PRINT "There is a mountain to the North"
PRINT "There is a cactus to the East"
PRINT "There is a river to the South"
PRINT "There is a shack to the East"
PRINT " "
INPUT "Type a direction:", direction$
IF direction$ = "north" THEN PRINT "Mountain"
```

And the output from [repl.it](https://repl.it/CKUI/19):

```
QBasic (qb.js)
Copyright (c) 2010 Steve Hanov
:
There is a mountain to the North
There is a cactus to the East
There is a river to the South
There is a shack to the East
:
Type a direction:  north
:
```

Comment: IF LEFT$(direction$, 5) = "north" THEN PRINT "Mountain"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works just fine when running QBasic in DOSBox, but apparently the QB JavaScript library used by repl.it doesn't work quite as QBasic does. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the input should just end, and the end-of-line sequence shouldn't be stored (or should be removed automatically). Unfortunately, the end-of-line sequence was not removed by the JavaScript library. The result is that the following works when it wouldn't work in QBasic:

```
IF direction$ = "north" + CHR$(10) THEN PRINT "Mountain"
```

In fact, I added a simple alternative to test the interpreter and received a parse error before I figured out the problem with `CHR$(10)`:

```
IF direction$ = "north" THEN PRINT "Mountain" ELSE PRINT "Not Mountain"
```

Based on this problem, I suggest running your program using the real thing (in a DOS emulator like DOSBox) or even something like [FreeBASIC](http://www.freebasic.net/) or [QB64](http://www.qb64.net/), both of which are based on QBasic and retain the same syntax, though I think QB64 is perhaps a little more compatible with the original.

Answer (score 1):

You could also strip off the trailing ascii characters:

```
INPUT X$
IF INSTR(X$, CHR$(10)) THEN
    X$ = LEFT$(X$, INSTR(X$, CHR$(10)) - 1) ' trim string
END IF
X$ = LCASE$(X$) ' and force case
```

That way X$ will contain only 'north'..